# Does setting precedent automatically make something ok for subsequent politicians to do the same thing?

Tags: united-states, president, law, congress

Surrounding the Impeachment trial of President Trump many news outlets have voiced that an acquittal will be setting precedent.

Does this mean that subsequent presidents will be able to do the same things and cite precedent without fear of retribution?

Is there any legal standing to setting precedent? Could `President A` set precedent with something and then `President B` could do the same thing and be impeached for doing that same exact thing?

I'm a bit confused how setting precedent holds any legal value.

Comment: "But he did unto me first."

Answer (score 27):

It should be noted, first of all, that impeachment is a political process and not a legal one.  This means that the precedent argument is not as strong as it would be in, for example, a Supreme Court case.

In a legal case, a large part of a court's job is to interpret the meaning of a law.  When a court makes a determination of the meaning of a law, then other courts are expected to apply the same meaning of a law to maintain consistency across the legal system.  After all, if different courts apply the same law in different ways, it would become very confusing as to what a law actually means.  This is unless or until a higher court rejects this interpretation on appeal, or legislation is passed to invalidate such an interpretation.

Meanwhile, one Congress cannot bind any of its successor Congresses.  They are under no obligation to look at precedent as they decide whether or not to impeach/convict.

Comment: This answer would be better with a sentence or two pointing out how a precedent argument in a subsequent impeachment trial might play out.

Comment: @phoog That is something that we cannot know, as it is a political process rather than a legal one.

Comment: @JoeC We've had presidential impeachment trials before - knowing how the precedents for previous ones would affect later ones is not an impossible thing.

Comment: +1, but "other courts are generally expected ..." is not really accurate. Lower courts are *obliged* to apply decisions of higher courts.

Comment: I think this need to come back to discussing impeachment to answer the question. In its current state, it's a discussion of *legal precedent* not really political precedent.

Comment: The legal/political distinction here seems questionable.  Impeachment rules are set by the Constitution, which however vague and prone to interpretation, is generally regarded as the highest *law* in the land.

Comment: @agc Only a handful of impeachment-related things are specified in the Constitution (i.e. that the House votes to impeach, the Senate holds the impeachment trial, and the Chief Justice presides.) The vast majority of impeachment-related rules are set by the House and Senate in their own rules, which aren't law at all and which they can change or vote to ignore on a whim.

Comment: "When a court makes a determination of the meaning of a law, then other courts are generally expected to apply the same meaning of a law" This is only true if a _higher_ court makes said determination. Other courts may take decisions by lower or pier courts into consideration, but they can (and somewhat-frequently do) end up ruling differently. Even Federal Circuit Courts of Appeals end up issuing conflicting rulings, a situation known as Circuit Split, where one ruling will be controlling in one part of the country and another ruling in a different part until the split is resolved.

Comment: I'm with @bob (oddly enough).  This feels like a good answer that then stops very abruptly.  Even if it's just something along the lines of "A future congress would not be so bound", it just needs something to tie it back to the question.

Comment: @reirab, A judge prone to sentencing whims is not in of himself a *de facto* negation of normal sentencing best practice.  An eccentric police officer prone to whimsically selective enforcement would neither be a normal or typical representative of good policing.  Similarly the whims of the most partisan senate faction since the last civil war do not in of themselves represent a negation of what impeachment law is for -- like a dumb judge, or a bad cop, they may not choose to do  their jobs, but those undone jobs remain all the more real.

Answer (score 24):

> Could President A set precedent with something and then President B could do the same thing and be impeached for doing that same exact thing?

Yes, absolutely. It is usually understood that Congress can impeach and remove a president for anything it deems official misconduct (so-called "high crimes and misdemeanors"). What Congress deems official misconduct can change from election to election (or minute to minute).

Answer (score 5):

Of course, it's not a matter of black letter law. But assuming a partisan situation, Democrats are unlikely to try and impeach another president for similar behavior, because they know the Republicans won't assist. (And if the Republicans do assist, it will make this impeachment look worse for them.) Any Republican trying to impeach a president for similar behavior will know the Democrats can simply quote their own words back at them, and will know that the Republicans are being grossly hypocritical. If the Republicans did have the power to force it through, it's going to get ugly, since that's clearly stating that impeachment is not about "high crimes", it's about who has the power.

(There is a note that Senate Majority Leader Mitch McConnell did have his words quoted back at him; it's also worth noting that he's polling quite a bit worse than the partisan lean of his state, Kentucky, especially surprising for a long-term Congressional member with power in Congress.)

Congress could pass laws against similar "quid pro quo", and then try and enforce those laws through impeachment, like was done against Johnson. But until if and when they do so, it's hard to imagine that something like this could be used for impeachment.

Comment: Since when does being judged as `grossly hypocritical` affect any politician? Quotes were thrown around dating from the Clinton impeachment and they had no effect on any politician so far as I can tell.

Comment: @doneal24 Generally I agree, but accusations of hypocrisy could be the final nail in the coffin for an already-beleaguered politician, especially if it's particularly egregious.

Comment: Yeah, I would have to agree with doneal. Hypocrisy is pretty much guaranteed with most politicians. And impeachment has nearly always been primarily about who has the power. Several of the House Democrats literally ran in the last election on the platform of impeaching Trump, even though the events for which they ultimately impeached him hadn't happened yet. That's not to say Trump's actions were in any way appropriate, but anyone who thinks the impeachment was motivated by anything other than politics is fooling themselves.

Comment: @doneal24 McConnell is an incredibly powerful politician, from a state that leans Republican (Cook Partisan Voting Index puts Kentucky at +15). I'd expect him to have his state on his side, but he's only polling +8 over his Democratic opponent. I'd say some of those quotes hit home. Moreover, we live in a partisan time; I'd expect it matter a lot more if people switched which party they voted for more, and if we don't start heading that way soon, I'm actively worried about the state of the Republic and the Democracy.

Comment: @reirab Police often catch someone and press charges only on the cases they can prove solidly; that doesn't mean their investigation on the other changes was political or that he didn't do them. Nor does it say anything about a police officer that they want to press a charge that prosecutors think is too weak to charge on. Trump did a lot of things you don't think were appropriate; House members differed on which were impeachable and on which to impeach on, but that's not evidence it wasn't motivated by purely political concerns.

Comment: Also, if it was purely political, and normal (as "since when" implies), why has Trump been but the third president to be impeached? In recent history, 1947-1949, 1995-2001, 2015-2017 we had a Democratic president and Republican house and senate, with Clinton. Between 1955-1961, 1969-1977, 1987-1993, and 2007-2009, we had a Republican president and Democratic house and senate, with Nixon (who wasn't impeached). Why those three presidents, especially when Trump held a majority in the Senate, and the rare modern times where one party has had 2/3rds of the Senate have been with the president?

Comment: @prosfilaes There's a political cost to impeachment, particularly when the impeachment has the appearance of political motivation. When you try to undo the results of an election, it can come back to bite you in your own next election. But U.S. politics has become so polarized - and there's such a visceral hate of Trump in particular - that a lot of Democrats were wanting to impeach him with no actual evidence of anything before he even set foot in office and then campaigned on it in the next election. The desire to impeach him long predated any actual evidence of wrongdoing.

Comment: @prosfilaes Going back to your analogy of criminal trials, if you start acquiring evidence that should require a warrant in a criminal trial before you have actual probable cause, then that evidence gets thrown out in court, even if it shows evidence beyond the shadow of a doubt that you committed a crime. You can't just go on a fishing expedition because you don't like someone and then prosecute them if you find something. See [fruit of the poisonous tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_of_the_poisonous_tree). To a lot of people who have been watching since 2016, this feels like that.

Comment: @reirab those of us who've been following Trump for a few decades in his career in NY real estate know that he's slimy enough that anyone who looks closely will find damaging evidence. Why do you think he's avoided disclosing his tax returns?  Why do you think he has sought to avoid having anyone from his administration testify? It's perfectly legal to go on a fishing expedition because you don't like someone and then prosecute them if you find something, as long as you don't violate the fourth amendment in doing it. But the fruit of the poisonous tree doctrine does not apply to impeachment.

Comment: @reirab Trump asked Russia to engage in criminal activity, hacking, at the cost of his opponents. His son met with Russian, foreign agents on the belief they had useful information that was almost certainly going to be the proceeds of criminal activity. That's evidence of wrongdoing. The standards of investigation are far from that of arrest or impeachment. (And I think all of us have been watching since 2016.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they could be impeached, but it might be more difficult.

The grounds for impeachment and removal in the Constitution are very vague, and it's up to Congress to interpret them and decide whether they apply to the current President's actions.

In doing so, they often look at history for guidance. They review documents written by the framers of the Constition to understand their intent. And they look for similarities in past impeachment proceedings. For example, a significant portion of the arguments made on both sides in the Trump impeachment cited analogies with previous impeachments (not just of Presidents, since there have been so few, but also the many judicial impeachments).

So while they're not legally bound by precedents, they can provide compelling arguments.